# Tomcat6 Service Setup; programatically concatenate JvmOptions using Batch File

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, tomcat6

This may bit a bit of a basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer on the web. I'm trying to automatically set up tomcat as a service through a batch file.

My batch file currently looks like this:

```
set memSize=512
set jvmOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
ECHO Setting up tomcat as a service. 
call service.bat install
ECHO Setting the memory allocation to a maximum of %memSize%
ECHO Using JVM options %jvmOptions%
Tomcat6 //US// --JvmMx=%memSize%  --Startup="auto" --JvmOptions=%jvmOptions%
```

The issue I'm facing is that running the --JvmOptions switch overwrites all the current java options that are set in the tomcat6w.exe.

So my question is, does anyone know how to have the --JvmOptions switch concatenate the passed value to the end of the current value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long hard search I did manage to find the answer in a code example.  But then to make me feel very foolish I noticed that the answer was also [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) right under my nose on the Tomcat6 Windows Service How To page.  By replacing the -- with ++ the option is concatenated rather than replacing the original.

So the batch file became.

```
set memSize=512
set jvmOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
ECHO Setting up tomcat as a service. 
call service.bat install
ECHO Setting the memory allocation to a maximum of %memSize%
ECHO Using JVM options %jvmOptions%
Tomcat6 //US// --JvmMx=%memSize%  --Startup="auto" ++JvmOptions=%jvmOptions%
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as this (if I understand your question correctly)

```
set memSize=512

REM I removed the quotes and reused the variable in its own definition
set jvmOptions=%jvmOptions%-XX:MaxPermSize=512M

ECHO Setting up tomcat as a service. 
call service.bat install
ECHO Setting the memory allocation to a maximum of %memSize%
ECHO Using JVM options %jvmOptions%

REM Added the quotes back here
Tomcat6 //US// --JvmMx=%memSize%  --Startup="auto" --JvmOptions="%jvmOptions%"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the jvmOptions aren't an environmental variable they're specific to the Tomcat6 service installation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old post, but I have to do a bunch of Tomcat uninstalls/installs due another application being upgraded (a term I use loosely) and was trying to figure out how to do something similar to avoid using the UI and ensure consistency.

Some scripting tips (based on my experience so far):

```
REM -- Use variables for the Tomcat install directory & executable:
set TomcatDir=%ProgramFiles%\Tomcat
set TomcatExe=%TomcatDir%\bin\Tomcat7.exe

REM -- If using multiple instances, turn these in to array
set TomcatInstance[1]=Tomcat7
set TomcatInstance[2]=MyAppInstance1
set TomcatInstance[3]=MyAppInstance2
set TomcatInstance[4]=MyAppInstance3
set TomcatInstance[5]=MyAppInstance4

REM -- When updating/adding Java options and you need to use a ";" between
REM -- values, single-quote the semi-colon, ';' so it isn't intepretted as a CrLf
REM -- For example,
call "%TomcatExe%" //US/%TomcatInstance% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.library.path=%TomcatDir%\bin';'%TomcatDir%\endorsed"

REM -- So to ensure all instances have the same settings...
for /L %I in (1,1,5) do (
    call "%TomcatExe%" //US/!TomcatInstance[%I]! ++JvmOptions "-Djava.library.path=%TomcatDir%\bin';'%TomcatDir%\endorsed"
)

REM -- Block scripts sections with setlocal/endlocal
REM -- "EnableDelayedExpansion" allows the above delayed variable expansion to occur
::--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==
:Routine_Name
::--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo script commands go here
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Note: This would be much easier in an actual scripting language (vbs, js or ps), but I need to leave the script "easy" to modify for whomever takes over for me when I leave my current gig.

FWIW, the how to doc for Tomcat7 is http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html.